# WordPress block transforms with InnerBlocks template

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

My plugin has a custom block that *contains* an innerblock template, defined in `edit()` like so...

```
const HEADING = [
    [
        "core/heading",
        {
            level: 2,
            placeholder: __("Enter a title", "myplugin"),
        },
    ],
];
```

...and later...

```
<div className="title">
    <InnerBlocks template={HEADING} templateLock="all" />
</div>
```

I want to allow existing `core/heading` blocks to be transformed into a `myplugin/my-heading` block, so I have the following code in `registerBlockType` to begin with...

```
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: "block",
            blocks: ["core/heading"],
            transform: ({ content }) => {
                console.log(content);
                return wp.blocks.createBlock("myplugin/my-heading");
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

This works insofar as it replaces a `core/heading` with a `myplugin/my-heading` block.

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to take the `content` and insert it into the innerblock template.

The [createBlock documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-blocks/#createBlock) is pretty basic and I can't find any example of how this might work when the content doesn't map onto any existing attributes.

**UPDATE**: Here's the full solution. I needed to create a block that matched my template and pass it as an array to the `innerblocks` parameter:

```
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: "block",
            blocks: ["core/heading"],
            transform: ({ content }) => {
                const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.createBlock("core/heading", {
                    content: content,
                    placeholder: __("Enter a title", "myplugin"),
                    level: 2,
                });
                return wp.blocks.createBlock("myplugin/my-heading", {}, [
                    innerBlocks,
                ]);
            },
        },
    ],
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example from the WordPress Docs on [Block Transforms](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-transforms/#block), shows how you can pass in `content` as the second parameter to `createBlock()`:

```
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: "block",
            blocks: ["core/heading"],
            transform: ({ content }) => {
                console.log(content);
                return wp.blocks.createBlock("myplugin/my-heading", {
                    content, // content is inserted here
                });
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

Example for your block with inner blocks:

```
transforms: {
    from: [
        {
            type: "block",
            blocks: ["core/heading"],
            transform: ( attributes, innerBlocks ) => {
                return wp.blocks.createBlock(
                    'myplugin/my-heading',
                    attributes,
                    innerBlocks
                );
            },
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: Right, but my block doesn't actually accept arbitrary InnerBlocks. It includes a single InnerBlock that is part of a locked template. I need to pass data into that locked template somehow.

Comment: @ebell Because you have the template, if the incoming innerblock isnt of that type, then it can't be added, so as the block you are transforming from/to is the allowed type for your template, then should be no issue. Did you apply my answer to your code, if it failed, what was the error?

Comment: Ok, so if I use `rawHandler` for the `innerblocks` parameter like so: `const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.rawHandler({HTML: "<h2>" + content + "</h2>"})` it does actually work, though I lose my custom placeholder text, which I do need to preserve. Is there a way I can plug this directly into my template, rather than leaving it to `rawHandler` to figure out?

Comment: I've also tried...
`const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.createBlock("core/heading", {content: content,placeholder: __("Enter a title", "myplugin"),level: 2,});` 
... but that produces the following error: 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.`

Comment: Now that I read that error more closely, it's easy to fix and the solution works: `const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.createBlock("core/heading", {content: content,placeholder: __("Enter a title", "myplugin"),level: 2,});` The param just needed to be passed as an array, i.e. `[innerBlocks]`